# Save file with Russian letters in the file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, cyrillic

I have this Python script that takes the info of a webpage and then saves this info to a text file. But the name of this text file changes from time to time and it can changes to Cyrillic letters sometimes, and some times Korean letters.

The problem is that say I'm trying to save the file with the name "бореиская" then the name will appear very weird when I'm viewing it in Windows.

I'm guessing I need to change some encoding at some places. But the name is being sent to the `open()` function:

```
server = "бореиская"
file = open("eu_" + server + ".lua", "w")
```

I am, earlier on, taking the server variable from an array that already has all the names in it.

But as previously mentioned, in Windows, the names appear with some very weird characters.

Comment: Which version of python are you using ? Unicode strings should be prefixed with `u"бореиская"` in python2 while in 3 unicode is default. Also while reading from streams you have encode/decode it to/from utf-8. [Relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: Using python 2.7, will try to apply the changes that are mentioned on the docs that u linked. Didn't found that before. Will get back with results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

Always use Unicode strings for file names and paths. E.g.:

```
io.open(u"myfile€.txt")
os.listdir(u"mycrazydirß")
```

In your case:

```
server = u"бореиская"
file = open(u"eu_" + server + ".lua", "w")
```

I assume `server` will come from another location, so you will need to ensure that it's decoded to a Unicode string correctly. See `io.open()`.

### Explanation

#### Windows

Windows stores filenames using UTF-16. The Windows i/o API and Python hides this detail but requires Unicode strings, else a string will have to use the correct 8bit codepage.

#### Linux

Filenames can be made from any byte string, in any encoding, as long as it's not ASCII "." or "..". As each system user can have their own encoding, you really can't guarantee the encoding one user used is the same as another. The `locale` is used to configure each user's environment. The user's terminal encoding also needs to match the encoding for consistency.

The best that can be hoped is that a user hasn't changed their locale and all applications are using the same locale. For example, the default locale may be: `en_GB.UTF-8`, meaning the encoding of files and filenames should be UTF-8.

When Python encounters a Unicode filename, it will use the user's locale to decode/encode filenames. An encoded string will be passed directly to the kernel, meaning you may get lucky with using "UTF-8" filenames.

#### OS X

OS X's filenames are always UTF-8 encoded, regardless of the user's locale. Therefore, a filename should be a Unicode string, but may be encoded in the user's locale and will be translated. As most user's locales are `*.UTF-8`, this means you can actually pass a UTF-8 encoded string or a Unicode string.

#### Roundup

For best cross-platform compatibility, always use Unicode strings as in most cases they will be translated to the correct encoding. It's really just Linux that has the most ambiguity, as some applications may choose to ignore the default locale or a user may have changed their locale to a non-UTF-8 version.

Comment: Thank you for the very good and descriptive comment. Sadly this did not work for me. I just got

    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I even tried to use u"".join(server) and got the same thing. Please note that I'm in python 2.7

Comment: As stated, `server` needs to be a Unicode object. You really ought to be decoding `server` at the point of input. However, you can try: `file = open(u"eu_" + server.decode("utf-8") + ".lua", "w")` or `file = open(u"eu_" + server.decode("cp1251") + ".lua", "w")`

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late replys but I've been really busy lately, I still want to learn this though. Still getting errors however:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-15: ordinal not in range(128)

print "Trying to get: " + server.decode("cp1251")

also tried with .decode("utf-8")

Comment: It sounds like `server` is now a Unicode. You do not need to encode or decode it when printing. `print` via stdout will automatically encode to the appropriate encoding for you. The only trouble you'll have is in Windows console, if you try to print characters out of your region. Then you'll have to use "win-unicode-console"

Comment: response = urllib2.urlopen(htmlLink.decode("utf-8"))

Link cus I can't seem to copy text from cmd :S
http://puu.sh/mZ4EO/229e2f28c9.png

Comment: 1) See previous comment about not using `decode()` 2) To copy and paste from Windows console: right click, select "mark", select text. Text is now in clipboard 3) We're now going off topic. The answers given answer your initial question. There's plenty of questions regarding UnicodeEncodeError on SO, which I advise you to look at. It will probably involve you reading the difference between encoded bytes and decoded Unicodes, and not arbitrarily throwing `decode()` and `encode()` around

Comment: But I'm not printing it anymore. I didn't end up on my clipboard. This is way too time consuming for such a trivial task but I guess that's my problem.

Comment: You're getting the error because you're arbitrarily decoding stuff that doesn't need decoding.

Comment: Managed to get it working by doing it all over again. You were right, I did randomly throw them around. So what I did was that every string enclosed  with " I put a u behind and let that switch them to unicode. The variable names I encoded with .encode("utf-8").

I also had a string that was concatenated. For this I used the u in the first concatenation because it was enclosed with citation marks. If it's not then I would assume that you would have to encode it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm viewing it in windows. ...Using python 2.7

use Unicode filenames on Windows. Python can use Unicode API there.

Do not use non-ascii characters in bytestring literals (it is explicitly forbidden on Python 3).

- use Unicode literals `u''` or add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the module
- make sure the encoding declaration (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) is correct i.e., your IDE/editor uses the specified encoding to save your Python source

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

server = u"бореиская"
with open(u"eu_{server}.lua".format(**vars()), "w") as file:
    ...
```

Comment: I even tried to use u"".join(server) and got the same thing. Got: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Thomja : do you understand that `type(server)` should be `unicode`? Note: `u""` creates Unicode string

Comment: But I can't add a u before a variable name? Like say I have a variable called test. I can't do utest because the it will try to find a variable called utest.

Comment: @Thomja :  the answer to your question in the title is: use Unicode filenames. If you don't know what is Unicode or how to get it in your specific case then ask a new question. It should be obvious that prepending `u` to a variable **name** won't convert the corresponding object  to Unicode (you should get `NameError: utest is not defined` exception)

Answer (score -1):

In Windows you have to encode filename probably to some of `cp125x` encoding but I don't know which one - probably `cp1251`.

```
filename = "eu_" + server + ".lua"

filename = filename.encode('cp1251')

file = open(filename, 'w')
```

In Linux you should use `utf-8`

Comment: Thanks, this will require some modification to my loop. But I will try this. Do I also have to do this for the contents of the file?

Comment: if you have russian letters in content probably you will have to encode too. But maybe you will need `utf-8` or other encoding.

Comment: you shouldn't do it (you should pass Unicode instead) and it won't work anyway. OP uses Python 2.7 and `server` is a non-ascii bytestring therefore  `filename.encode('cp1251')` produces `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode ...`

Comment: Still got the weird text.

Comment: @furas, on Windows you should pass just Unicodes for file paths - there's no need to encode. On Linux, you can not guarantee the user's locale and terminal emulation is UTF-8  based, so you may make filenames that the user can not see properly. Again, use Unicodes.

Comment: Tried by addin the u before string names. Still get

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in postion 15-22: character maps to <undefined>